# html5 animate canvas with elements already drawn

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Can I get some help with animating elements on a canvas?  I would like to get the elements already drawn on the canvas and "move" them off the canvas and display the new elements.  My functions are in javascript and work nicely.  I would just like to add animation.  TIA.

Comment: Erase everything, draw it again in new position.  Repeat.

Comment: What @cwolves said. Or use a library like [fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com) that takes care of this.

Comment: the only issue is that I don't know what will be placed on the canvas at the time animation starts.

Answer (score -1):

just have an event handler control the `left` of the style for that canvas's id and then specify a loop to have it change or move to the left/right based on time.

```
(function() {
var speed = 10,
movePic = function(moveBy) {
    var el = document.getElementById("animationStyle"),
        left = el.offsetLeft


    if ((moveBy > 0 && left > 399) || (moveBy < 0 && left < 51)) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setInterval(function () {
            movePic(moveBy * -1);
        }, speed);
    } 
    el.style.left = left + moveBy + "px";
};
var timer = setInterval(function () {
movePic(3)
}, speed);
}());
```

This would move it back and forth, this is an example that should help you get started.

Comment: `function moveCanvas() { 
var speed = 10;
 //alert('move canvas');
 movePic = function(moveBy) {
     var el = document.getElementById('Canvas1');
     var ctx = theCanvas.getContext("2d");
     left = ctx.offsetLeft;

  if ((moveBy > 0 && left > 399) || (moveBy < 0 && left < 51)) {
      clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setInterval(function () { 
             movePic(moveBy * -1);
         }, speed);
  }
  ctx.style.left = left + moveBy + "px";
  } var timer = setInterval(function () { movePic(3);
 }, speed);
 }`

Comment: "animating elements on a canvas" , he means canvas draw element not dom tag element . Maybe i am wrong .